# Using image sheets with graphics.newMask() in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, masking

In Corona SDK, I'd like to use an image sheet frame with `graphics.newMask()` instead of an image file name. So instead of:

```
myMaskPtr = graphics.newMask("myMask.png");
```

I'd like to use something like:

```
myImageSheetPtr = graphics.newImageSheet( "myImageSheetMasks.png", mySheetData );
myMaskPtr = graphics.newMask( myImageSheetPtr, 2 );
```

Any ideas? Is it possible?

Comment: Lua has nothing like pointers, off topic, but just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Corona support:

```
Hello,

graphics.newMask does not currently support imageSheet images. I will add that to our to-do list.

Regards, Tom
```

So, no it isn't possible.